# Check image size using byte array

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bitmap

I am trying to upload an image to the server. However, before I perform an upload I perform a check to see if the image size is greater than 2MB.
After receiving the image from the activity result I run the following code

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(this.Activity.ContentResolver, uri);
                                //int imageSize = 79030;
                                //float size = (bitmap.RowBytes * bitmap.Height) / 1024;
                                //float seasonDrop = size / 10000;
                                //double actualsizeMb = Math.Round(seasonDrop, 1);
                                // Rotate the image if required. Samsung devices have an Exif property that usually rotates the image.
      bitmap = rotateImageIfRequired(bitmap, this.Activity, uri);
      int size = bitmap.ByteCount;
      var bytesize = bitmap.RowBytes * bitmap.Height; 
      var buffer = Java.Nio.ByteBuffer.Allocate(bytesize);
      bitmap.CopyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
      buffer.Rewind();
      var bytes = new byte[bytesize];
      float length = bytes.Length / (1024 * 1024);
```

I try and upload a 1.96MB image. However when I place a break point on length the value that i get back is 10MB. This should not be possible for an image to increase in size like this.

Comment: `upload a 1.96MB image` What exactly is 1.96 MB?

Comment: `trying to upload an image to the server.`. You try to upload all pixels of a bitmap. You did not tell where that bitmap comes from. But if you want to upload files then upload those files directly and dont start messing around with BitmapFactory or Bitmaps.

Comment: What is it that the server wants to receive? A file or a stream of bytes which it cannot decode? Or can it?

Comment: But i cannot upload an image that is greater than 2MB that is why i was performing this condition.

Comment: Ever heard of [image compression](https://www.google.com/search?q=image+compression&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and of [image file formats](https://www.google.com/search?q=image+compression&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=image+file+formats)?

Comment: You have not answered my simple questions and comments.

Comment: @greenapps The image that i try and upload is  1.96MB

Comment: @greenapps The image comes from my pictures folder in my phone. Then i take the result of the activity result which is the image then try and check the size using bitmap factory. Thanks i now understand not to use bitmap to check for size. Any suggestions, compression is not the solution i wanted to take

Comment: `The image that i try and upload is 1.96MB`.Where and how did you determine that it is 1.96B ? I asked that before. And is it a file?

Comment: `Then i take the result of the activity result which is the image`.  You are not even telling which action/intent you started which delivered a result. And `onActivityResult()` will not deliver images but `uri`'s.

Answer (score 1):

1.9 MB might be the compressed size as the image is likely in jpeg or png format (which are compressed) if from the camera or the gallery. When you check the bitmap size, you are checking uncompressed size of the image, which will be much larger than the compressed size. When you get the file reference, just check the size of the file as it is without converting the image to a bitmap. You could use the .NET FileInfo.Length property to check the compressed size of the image file.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length(v=vs.110).aspx

From the link above:

```
// Make a reference to a directory.
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");
// Get a reference to each file in that directory.
 FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();
// Display the names and sizes of the files.
 Console.WriteLine("The directory {0} contains the following files:", di.Name);
 foreach (FileInfo f in fiArr)
      Console.WriteLine("The size of {0} is {1} bytes.", f.Name, f.Length);
```